# Gradle 5.3 publish SNAPSHOT BadRequest Error

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I am receiving an error in my circleci build when running the gradle publish step. I am using gradle 5.3 and realize they have change this functionality in 5.4.1. However, I do not understand why this is failing in the version that I am using.

```
group = 'com.talentreef.notification.commons'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releaseRepoUrl = "https://nexus.trdev.co/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
            def snapshotRepoUrl = "https://nexus.trdev.co/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotRepoUrl : releaseRepoUrl
            credentials {
                username = rootProject.ext.nexus.username
                password = rootProject.ext.nexus.password
            }
        }
    }
}

    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'https://nexus.trdev.co/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/talentreef/notification/commons/notification-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/notification-commons-1.0.0-20190619.182943-1.jar'.
      > Could not PUT 'https://nexus.trdev.co/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/talentreef/notification/commons/notification-commons/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/notification-commons-1.0.0-20190619.182943-1.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

Okay, so it seems like it fails because the repository is a policy type "release" instead of a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Check the nexus.log file, there should be a message there saying why the request was rejected.

Comment: Thank you, changing the repository police from release to snapshot fixed it.